# Graphic objects update without skip, vba

Tags: vba

I have a code, for example the class named `MyClass` and expect after each step the result is updated in the excel workbook, and some chart and graphic object is updated dynamically.
The delay of updating cells, charts and images is just ok but I have to add an additional pause because otherwise it will skip all the process and jumps graphic update to the end of code execution.
What should I do to getrid of unintended pause?

```
Public a As Double
Public b As Double
Public counter As Integer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    a = Range("A1")
    b = Range("B1")
    counter = 1
End Sub
Public Sub some_calculation()
    a = a + b
End Sub
Public Sub graphic_update()
    counter = counter + 1
    Cells(count, 1) = a
    Sheet1.Shapes("Picture 1").Rotation = Sheet1.Shapes("Picture 1").Rotation + 45
End Sub
Public Function pause(pause_time As Double)
    Start_Time = Timer
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until (Timer - Start_Time) >= pause_time
End Function
Sub test()
    Dim obj1 As New MyClass
    For i = 1 To 10
        obj1.some_calculation
        obj1.graphic_update    ' if I had a kind of confirmation of previous line execution, which is cells update, to go to the next one, it would be just ok.
        obj1.pause (0.001)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding some DoEvents in your code

Comment: You mean for example in graphic_update function?

Comment: Anywhere where you want to give Excel time to catch up.

Comment: Sorry @TimWilliams could you give a clue to use DoEvents, because actually I didn't manage to solve it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you requested an example of DoEvents - I would try something like this:

```
Public Sub graphic_update()
    counter = counter + 1
    Cells(count, 1) = a
    Sheet1.Shapes("Picture 1").Rotation = Sheet1.Shapes("Picture 1").Rotation + 45
    DoEvents '<<<
End Sub
```